# Is it Possible to vs-15 project open from vs-13 without any error?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, project, solution

I am using Visual Studio 2015, but I have to show my project from Visual Studio 2013 pc, Is it harmful for solution file? or any file? Visual Studio 2015 have some extra feature, that cant's contain Visual Studio 2013. Now how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I want to recommend not to mix different versions of Visual Studio. Please strictly create different folders for different versions e.g . one for VS2013 and another for VS2015. 
You know - different versions installed on one PC is possible.

If you really want to go one version back to show your VS2015 project in a VS2013 IDE make sure you have a backup in a safe place. You maybe warned - don't make the mistake of mixing code versions when you switch from one PC to another.

Try to open and show for your needs in your special development environment by yourself it is possible but be careful like mentioned above. Having used the highest dotnet version possible in VS2015 you'll get errors.